# Calculation between multiple tables as SQL query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have following code which works well as SQL query run in rails. I want to convert this to rails syntax.

```
sql.update "UPDATE `chsdesk`. `units`, `unit_types`, `bill_setups` 
SET units.property_tax=unit_types.tax_area * bill_setups.rate_sqft_month + bill_setups.rate_unit_month, 
WHERE bill_setups.head_name ='Property Tax' AND units.unit_type_id = unit_types.id;";
sql.update "UPDATE `chsdesk`. `units`, `unit_types`, `bill_setups`
```

unit_types->   has_many :units
There is no other association possible between these tables.

I will be highly obliged if someone can help.  I can provide more details if requested.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far, and why it didn't work?

Comment: That SQL most certainly does not work with PostgreSQL, don't you mean [tag:mysql] instead of [tag:postgresql]? Anyway, I've re-tagged this to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

For quick solution I can suggest to use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE `chsdesk`. `units`, `unit_types`, `bill_setups` 
SET units.property_tax=unit_types.tax_area * bill_setups.rate_sqft_month + bill_setups.rate_unit_month, 
WHERE bill_setups.head_name ='Property Tax' AND units.unit_type_id = unit_types.id")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code is working with mysql.  How do I make it work with Postgres.  I would love to have it written in Rails command code if possible.